# Where does windows stores the dump file if my application crashes?

Tags: windows-10, minidumps

Does windows creates a dump file (by default) if my application crashes?

If yes what is the path where it gets created?

Comment: Crash dumps (configure in Advanced System Settings, Advanced, Startup and Recovery) are for hardware crashes, not application crashes.  Look in Reliability History for stop working errors and analyze these errors.

Comment: @John Thanks. So if I understand correctly windows does not create a memory dump if application crashes, but creates it on system (os) crash.

Comment: That is correct. Application errors do not create crash dump files. I have expanded all this in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash Dumps are for hardware errors.

If dumps have been enabled and one occurs, it will usually be in:  `C:\Windows\Minidump`

Otherwise, application errors may occur:

(a) in the application's dump file location (xPlorer2 does this.  OR

(b) in Reliability History. This is the Windows 10 location for creating and reporting WER reports. These are error reports that Windows uses to correct issues.

[image]